# CoreData - TableView init with Objects?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, tablecell

It is easy to create tableView with some data already using NSMutableArray and initWithObjects method.

However, is it possible to do the same when using core data?

i.e. let's say that entity is called MyEntity and Attributes are name and value.

table cell has identifiew myCell.

Comment: Google "core data seed database"

Comment: thanks. I was missing keyword :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just ask your model some Data that you'd put into an NSArray ? It's as easy as that !

Comment: I would, but have no idea how to do that :(

Comment: Ok, then you have to learn the basic of Core Data first. You'll want to check this great tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: another tutorial inc. video http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/2012/intro-to-core-data/

Comment: thanks guys!

do you have any tutorial for this problem?
I have been tapping in the dark for some time.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801963/pass-core-data-entity-attribute-from-viewcontroller-a-to-b